# webview and android eclipse

Tags: android, webview

I have a HTML5 webpage, I want to use webview for Android DSK.

This is my androidmanifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.myfirstapp"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

And this is my activitymain.xml on the layout folder:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />


<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What else should I do? And where to put that code?

Google android documentation says this:

To load a web page in the WebView, use loadUrl(). For example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

But where should I put these lines of code? In a new file? I've tried a lot of things with no success.

Comment: Just put that two lines of WebView code in onCreate() method of your activity, below setContentView(...).

Comment: @Adrian Diaz see the solution posted to solve your problem.

Comment: abhi  , ok could you post a example code and where can i put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this from your `MainActivity.java` file:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView webView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        }

    }
```

Here is a good reference with example:

[Android WebView Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Comment: i dont have a mainactivity.java file

Comment: @AdrianDiaz then add `MainActivity.java` under this package `com.example.myfirstapp` and add posted content with that. Please go through with the reference link for the full example. There is a example download link is available too. So you will get much better idea from it.

Comment: activity cant be resolved as a type,  webview cant be resolved as a type,

Comment: @AdrianDiaz see my edit. You need to import required and used packages for that.

Comment: ok patrik, i think its working now, but one last error in the line:

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    it shows the message: "using this can xss vunerabilities"

Comment: @AdrianDiaz that will be a warning only you can ignore that. If it solve your problem then you can mark this answer as accepted.